# Get member data form plugin staff-member-list

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I would like to get the emails of all members. I could not figure out where the data like name, phone, email etc. is stored. On database? I could not find those data on database.

How to get all the emails with my own PHP file?

[Plugin Simple Staff List](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-staff-list/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those fields are stored as meta data for a post. From the plugin source code (admin-save-data.php):

```
update_post_meta($post->ID,"_staff_member_email",$_POST["_staff_member_email"]);
```

Normally you'd be able to see these when editing a post, but, custom fields prefixed with `_` are invisible. This particular meta data is associated with a custom post, so it 'loads' when you view the staff listing post. For a manual query, look at the wp_postmeta table for a meta_key labeled **_staff_member_email**.

A specific example of how this query is performed by using WP_Query is located in the user-view-show-staff-list.php file, near the shortcode. Here is a refactored version of the shortcode function:

```
function get_all_staff_info() {
    $ret = array();
    $staff = new WP_Query(array(
        "post_type" => "staff-member",
        "posts_per_page" => -1,
        "orderby" => "menu_order",
        "post_status" => "publish"
    ));

    if( $staff->have_posts() ) {
        while( $staff->have_posts() ) {
            $staff->the_post();
            $custom = get_post_custom();

            $ret[] = array(
                "name" => get_the_title(),
                "name_slug" => basename(get_permalink()),
                "title" => $custom["_staff_member_title"][0],
                "email" => $custom["_staff_member_email"][0],
                "phone" => $custom["_staff_member_phone"][0],
                "bio" => $custom["_staff_member_bio"][0]
            );
        }
        wp_reset_query();
    }
    return( $ret );
}
```

With this function, all you have to do is call `$staff = get_all_staff_info();` and loop through it. For sake of readability, I left out a few fields which you can locate in above-mentioned file, but the output looks like a standard array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Cookie
        [name_slug] => cookie
        [title] => Second cat
        [email] => cookie@example.com
        [phone] => 123-456-7890
        [bio] => Meow.
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [name] => Lily
        [name_slug] => lily
        [title] => First cat
        [email] => lily@example.com
        [phone] => 555-555-5555
        [bio] => Meow? Meow. Meoow?
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks pp19pp. Do you also know, how I can get the photo-url of each member?

Comment: There are a couple of lines in the user-view-show-staff-list.php file that you can repurpose for that. Look for photo and photo_url lines and add them to the $ret array.